# Passing PipelineParameter DataPath in Azure ML

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service, mlops, azureml-python-sdk

The problem with below code is that currently it does not run because of error in line 27:

**raise ValueError("Unexpected input type: %s" % type(input))
ValueError: Unexpected input type: <class 'azureml.pipeline.core.graph.PipelineParameter'>**

If I uncomment second data_path_pipeline_param, everything runs as it should. I do not really get why it expects DataPathComputeBinding to be passed.

```
    datastore = Datastore(workspace=ws, name="my-datastore")
    data_path = DataPath(datastore=datastore, path_on_datastore='input_data')
    data_path_pipeline_param = PipelineParameter(name="input_data", default_value=data_path)
    # data_path_pipeline_param = (PipelineParameter(name="input_data", default_value=datapath),
    #                             DataPathComputeBinding(mode='mount'))

    verify_datastores_step = PythonScriptStep(
        name='Save file to datastores',
        source_directory='verify_datastores_step',
        script_name='save_to_datastores.py',
        arguments=["--path", data_path_pipeline_param],
        inputs=[data_path_pipeline_param],
        runconfig=pipeline_run_config,
        allow_reuse=False

    )
```

Answer (score 0):

The **"inputs"** parameter is only taking in these types of data:

```
 :param inputs: A list of input port bindings.
        :type inputs: list[typing.Union[azureml.pipeline.core.graph.InputPortBinding,
                        azureml.data.data_reference.DataReference,
                        azureml.pipeline.core.PortDataReference,
                        azureml.pipeline.core.builder.PipelineData,
                        azureml.pipeline.core.pipeline_output_dataset.PipelineOutputFileDataset,
                        azureml.pipeline.core.pipeline_output_dataset.PipelineOutputTabularDataset,
                        azureml.data.dataset_consumption_config.DatasetConsumptionConfig]]
```

This is taken from documentation code from PythonScriptStep(). With only PipelineParameter you are not defining how you are sending data to the compute, you are not defining if you are **using download/mount mode.**